# Error undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'require('webpage').create()') when running Casper.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, casperjs

Dear StackOverflow Users
I'm trying to use casper.js and phantomJS to scrape content from a webpage that uses React to render the content

I've downloaded casper.js and Phantom.js added the environment variable path. 
But when I run the command casperjs filename.js I'm getting this error :

```
C:\wamp64\www\appli>TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'require('webpage').create()')
  C:/wamp64/www/appli/phantomjs:/platform/casper.js:2922 in createPage
  C:/wamp64/www/appli/phantomjs:/platform/casper.js:1895 in start
```

---

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
casper.start('http://casperjs.org/');

casper.then(function() {
    this.echo('First Page: ' + this.getTitle());
});

casper.thenOpen('http://phantomjs.org', function() {
    this.echo('Second Page: ' + this.getTitle());
});

casper.run();
```

Comment: Youssef, at this point in time you should definitely move to [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/) for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yes absolutely true, I Tried Puppeteer and it's working fine right now